# Spatial coordinates in Eulerian specification of velocity field

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, flow

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) summarized the relationship between Eulerian and Lagrangian specification as follows:

$$\mathbf{u}\left(\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x}_0,t), t \right) = \frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial t} \left(\mathbf{x}_0,t \right)$$

I understand $\mathbf{x}_0$ as time-independent initial position of a single fluid particle and $\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x}_0,t)$ returns position of that particle at time $t$.

I thought in Eulerian specification spatial coordinate $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbf{u}\left(\mathbf{x}, t \right)$ is time-independent. Yet in the above equation, $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x}_0,t)$ which makes $\mathbf{x}$ time-dependent? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To help understand what is happening, an exemple can be useful. Consider the time-independent (Eulerian) velocity field : $$\vec{u(M)}=ax \vec{e_x}$$

We are looking for the trajectory $X(x_0,t)$ of the particle which is in $x_0$ at time $t=0$ (Lagrangian).

We must therefore write that **the velocity of a fluid particle at $t$ is equal to the field velocity at the point where the particle is at instant $t$**: $$V(x_0,t)=\frac{d X(x_0,t)}{dt}=u(X_0(t),t)=aX(x_0,t)$$ $$\frac{d X(x_0,t)}{dt}=aX(x_0,t)$$ whose solution is $X(x_0,t)=x_0 e^{at}$ which is the lagrangian position of a fluid particle.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify what is $M$?

Comment: $M$ is simply the position variable in eulerian description : $v(M) = v(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the coordinate $x$ in the Eulerian description is generally time-independent. The above equation is a comparison of velocities of one fluid particle in both different descriptions, and this comparison has to be made at the right point, namely where the particle is. Which is why you enter the evaluation of its trajectory at time $t$, $X(x_0,t)$, for the position $x$ where you are using the Eulerian velocity field.